# tcpdump: why ack number greater than sack number?

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpdump

I use `tcpdump` to troubleshot network problem, and found one record that ack number is greater than sack number:
[image]

Why ack number greater than sack number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is compatible with a Duplicate Selective Acknowledgement as described in [RFC 2883](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2883#section-4.1.1) which adds DSACK to the SACK mechanism described in [RFC 2018](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2018).

Here's an [example from the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2883#section-4.1.1):

> Because several ACK packets are lost, the data sender retransmits
> packet 3000-3499, and the data receiver subsequently receives a
> duplicate segment with sequence numbers 3000-3499.  The receiver sends
> an acknowledgement with the cumulative **acknowledgement field set to
> 4000**, and the first, **D-SACK block specifying sequence numbers
> 3000-3500**.
>
> ```
>  Transmitted    Received    ACK Sent
>  Segment        Segment     (Including SACK Blocks)
>
>  3000-3499      3000-3499   3500 (ACK dropped)
>  3500-3999      3500-3999   4000 (ACK dropped)
>  3000-3499      3000-3499   4000, SACK=3000-3500
>                                        ---------
> ```

[Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2883#section-5) describes how to identify a DSACK:

> In order for the sender to check that the first (D)SACK block of an
> acknowledgement in fact acknowledges duplicate data, the sender should
> compare the sequence space in the **first SACK block** to the cumulative
> ACK which is carried IN THE SAME PACKET.  **If the SACK sequence space
> is less than this cumulative ACK**, it is an indication that the segment
> identified by the SACK block has been received more than once by the
> receiver.

So in this case ACK > SACK. This should happen only if packets from receiver to sender (meaning ACKs) got lost which then later triggered a (useless) resend of data from the sender which is even later reported back from the receiver to the sender with a DSACK. This information might be used in some congestion algorithms. I can't know if this is compatible with your capture, but that's something to check.

For example, on Linux DSACK is probably active by default:

```
# sysctl -ar 'net\.ipv4\.tcp_d?sack'
net.ipv4.tcp_dsack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
```